# Error LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts

Tags: linq, join, entity-framework-5

I am getting an error while executing following query

**Error:**
*The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts*

**Query:**

```
var wordlePuzzle = (from wp in wordlepostitionRepository.All
join wtc in wordletextclueRepository.All on wp.WordleTexCluetId equals wtc.WordleTextClueId
join w in wordleRepository.All on wtc.WordleId equals w.WordleId
where wtc.WordleId == id
select new WordlePuzzle
{
   Row = w.WordleRow,
   Column = w.WordleColumn,
   Title = w.WordleTitle,
   DifficultyLevel = DifficultyLevel.Easy,
   Duration = w.WordleDuration,
   ExpiresOn = w.ExpireDate
});
```

I have tried with appending `.AsEnumerable();` after end of the query but still it is giving an error.

I have only single Database for all those tables.

Comment: Well, you've got three different repositories in there... it's not clear how you're expecting them to all work together.

Comment: You'll probably want to introduce a unit of work pattern to share the same context instance across different repositories

Comment: Can you please help me to resolve this issue? because i am very new in LINQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at implementing the unit of work pattern so that you can share a context instance across repositories.

There are many examples on the web, e.g. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application